# Is there other way to get the Microsoft Edge DevTools Preview without Microsoft store?

Tags: webview, uwp, microsoft-edge

I always debug the WebView control with VS, I refer to the this official document [Debug a WebView control in a UWP App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-a-webview-control?view=vs-2017).

Recently, I found there is a best way to debug the WebView control by using the 
[Microsoft Edge DevTools Preview App](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-edge-devtools-preview/9mzbfrmz0mnj?activetab=pivot:overviewtab).

The problem is that it seems the only way to install the tools is Microsoft Store. Unfortunately the Miscrosoft Store is blocked on my machine, I want to know is there any other way to get the Microsoft Edge DevTools Preview tool? Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this article https://windowsreport.com/download-microsoft-store-apps-without-store which seems to show a way of doing this.

I cannot state if it definitely works yet as I have to wait for my IT to department to decide if it can be allowed.

Steps are:

- Visit https://store.rg-adguard.net/
- Enter https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/microsoft-edge-devtools-preview/9mzbfrmz0mnj
- Download the file ending in appxbundle (to it's own directory not just "downloads")
- Open Powershell as Admin
- Execute something like `Add-AppxPackage -Path "C:\Users\WindowsReport\Downloads\ee2546d7-f0e5-4aa2-be54-032299162322"` (change path to the download directory you used earlier)
- If you get errors you may need to download additional files from the same place you got the appxbundle file